# CSS Dropdown menu indenting on dropdown

Tags: html, css

The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/82V7X/)

I cannot figure out why there is an 'indent' in the drop down links. Please help? I am not an expert at this, so this is confusing me.

```
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;

    float:left;
    width:100%;

    position:relative;
    z-index:99;

} 
#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#nav ul{
    background:#fff;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
}
#nav  ul li{
    padding-top:1px;
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#nav li:hover ul{
    left:0;
} 
#nav li:hover a{
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav li:hover ul a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{
    background:#333;
}

#nav ul{
    background:#fff;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
}

#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px;
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#nav li:hover ul{
    left:0;
}
#nav li:hover a{
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{
    background:#333;
}
```

and the `html` is in the jsfiddle.

Comment: #nav li {
float: left;
/* margin-right: 10px; */
position: relative;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UL` has a default padding so bullet points don't appear outside the list.

Just add consideration for it to your `ul` like;

```
#nav ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82V7X/3/)

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: @susheel It works because there is a default padding of `~40px` on `ul` elements.. Not sure why this was downvoted.. 1+.

Comment: you could have put a note so that the user understands

Comment: Did I seriously just get a down vote on a correct answer? The reality is the question could have been closed for showing lack of research in the first place.

Comment: just answering is not enough, we need to explain the user why are we doing this so that next time he doesn't do same mistake. a small not would have been enough

Comment: @susheel He did explain. There isn't much to explain anyways. This is a valid answer.

Comment: reset css is the basic step, we need to say http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ I upvoted though

Comment: @susheel the OP made no mistake simply by trying to learn an answer without putting much effort towards researching it first. Quit trolling and let the dude enjoy his remedy man. At least I didn't vote to close it and just post a link to the docs, relax amigo.

Comment: @susheel For the record, you didn't upvote this.. *sigh*. http://imgur.com/jfYK3KI

Comment: yes I wanted to but locked :P :P I added an useful edit which was ignored which caused the downvote

Comment: no worries, we're here to help each other however we can.

Comment: chilll enjoy the weekend :D

Comment: @susheel same at ya brother, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The margin-right of 10 px is causing the indent

```
#nav li{
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  position:relative;
}
```

Try this:

```
#nav li{
  float:left;
  margin-right:0;
  position:relative;
}
```